# How can I transfer my SteamGuard key to the Steam mobile app?

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

I'd like to use Steam's mobile Android app, but in order to do so I need to either find a way to transfer my SteamGuard key to my phone, or reset my SteamGuard *(which I'd rather not do because it involves a temporary trade-ban)*.

I'm currently using [WinAuth](https://winauth.github.io/winauth/index.html), but I imagine the process is the same regardless of what authenticator app you're currently using.

Has anyone figured out how to successfully transfer a SteamGuard key into Steam Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not transfer your SteamGuard Authenticator to an alternative device without receiving a temporary ban.